# One folder doesn't have write access - samba share

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, samba, fstab

I have an external HD in NTFS format setup to share from my router.

Here is the fstab entry I have for mounting in Ubuntu:

> //rt-n66u-8fe8/data   /mnt/rt-n66u-8fe8/data      cifs    guest,_netdev,uid=matt,gid=matt,rw,dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0666 0 0

All folders have write permissions except for the Music folder:

```
matt@matt:/mnt/rt-n66u-8fe8/data$ ll
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 matt matt    0 Dec 29 12:00 ./
drwxrwxrwx 4 matt matt 4096 Jan 14 14:36 ../
drwxrwxrwx 1 matt matt    0 Jul  6  2015 Audio/
drwxrwxrwx 1 matt matt    0 Aug 25  2014 Courses/
drwxrwxrwx 1 matt matt    0 Dec 29 12:00 documentaries/
drwxrwxrwx 1 matt matt    0 Jul 14  2014 Downloads/
drwxrwxrwx 1 matt matt    0 Dec 29 12:01 movies/
dr-xr-xr-x 1 matt matt    0 Jan 20 11:17 Music/
drwxrwxrwx 1 matt matt    0 Dec 29 12:03 Sports/
drwxrwxrwx 1 matt matt    0 Oct  7  2014 Videos/
```

Trying to change the permissions gives the following error:

```
matt@matt:/mnt/rt-n66u-8fe8/data$ chmod 0777 Music/
chmod: changing permissions of ‘Music/’: Permission denied
```

In fact, I can't change permissions for anything.

If I plug the HD into my computer via USB, I can write to Music/.  The problem only occurs through the samba share.  What can I do to be able to write to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by:

1. Plugged external HD into computer so I had write access
2. Renamed Music to Music2
3. Created a new Music folder
4. Copied all the data from Music2 to Music
5. Deleted Music2
6. Plugged external HD into router and Music folder was now writeable

Answer (score 0):

According to your network location you're running an Asus RT-N66U and looking at [the similar firmware screenshot](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-seCC6EJ1_tE/VJSP0rEZhEI/AAAAAAAAFyQ/7m4rI1qNKK0/s1600/asus_samba2.jpg) it appears you have R/W configuration available on the router itself, make sure the user you're connecting as has R/W and not just R permission to the music folder share.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes I have checked that and it is set to R/W.  Actually I have guest  login turned on which defaults everything to R/W.

Comment: Hm alright first check for a firmware update this is an old issue then try chmod as root, if that doesn't work check out the ntfs attributes using `getfattr -d Music` this appears to be a common issue with these routers and ntfs drives so, if it's not too much trouble, formatting to ext3 appears to solve the problem for other users.